# How to do a safe (constraint) implicit join in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I consider a safe JOIN one which is constrained by its foreign key. And an implicit one which only mentions its target.

In SQLAlchemy, `session.query(User).join(Addresse)` might or might not be constraint, depending on whether SQLAlchemy knows about the relation between User and Addresses.

Sometimes I construct a complicated query and I want to make sure all joins are constraint. How can I check that? I would like best if SQLAlchemy gives me an exception when an implicit `.join(table)` didn’t find its foreign key...

Example for “complicated query”:

`session.query(addr_alias1).join(User).join(addr_alias2)`

For the last join, a overly explicit way would be `.join(addr_alias2, User.addresses)`, but as I said, I want an implicit syntax, which barks if it failed.

Comment: have you tried it?  when you say a.join(b) without an ON clause, it relies exclusively upon ForeignKey() constraint objects to determine the JOIN, otherwise it will raise an exception.

Comment: Gosh! I’m actually not sure what I tried and what not... But at least I found a documentation bug, then. :-P  The documentation/tutorial really sound like the join is done in any case (and gets constraint only if a foreign key is found).

Comment: here's the docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html#using-joins  "SQLAlchemy figured out how to JOIN the two tables ! The ON condition of the join, as it’s called, was automatically generated based on the ForeignKey object which we placed on the addresses table way at the beginning of this tutorial." - what docs are you looking at ?

Comment: The documentation you quote: does it say anything about throwing exceptions or failing otherwise? No. – It is already clear from my question that I’m aware of join() constructing a condition _whenever_ it finds a foreign key!

Comment: [ORM Tutorial: using joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins) says “If there were no foreign keys, or several, Query.join() works _better_ when one of the following [more explicit] forms are used:” Implying that it still works _at all_ if no foreign key is found (by doing a Cartesian product: a JOIN without ON, or even a CROSS JOIN to jump safety nets of some databases).

Comment: anyway, your question states, "I would like best if SQLAlchemy gives me an exception when an implicit .join(table) didn’t find it’s foreign key...", and the answer is, "it does".  So your problem is solved, aside from your complaints about documentation (for which [pull requests](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/develop.html#bitbucket) are highly welcome), right?

Comment: Right. – Okay... answer “it does” and I accept.

Comment: So as far as docs.  You have tutorial narration, which tries to get across the general usage pattern without much specificity, then the API docs.  Things like exceptions and complete behavioral contracts are better in API docs.  So join() needs real API docs, tutorials need to refer to them including ORM join making use of core join, then tighten up ambiguous phrases in tutorial docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy already does so.

Unfortunately, the tutorial suggests otherwise and the API documentation doesn’t clear that up.

Comment: Perhaps you could submit some documentary patches.